# Which hadoop framework(s) can be used in near RDBMS scenario

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hbase

We are in analysis phase for a project in which we are replacing old storing system to be based on hdfs and hive used for reporting and viewing.

But we got a request if we can make use of hdfs to use it in replacing part of database work.

The scenarios expected as following;

1. Tables will store daily traffic data.. around 400 monitoring point.
2. Some of the tables in point 1 will be used as an input to a process that will make some transforms and dump to other tables.
3. Tables in points 1&2 shall be used as base tables for views that will be used in a reporting portal. That will can be accessed any time by users.
4. Expecting wrong loading in any step, so tables should supports delete/update for some rows.
5. Around 50% of tables can exceed hundreds of millions of records.. but others will be 1k, 50k, 1M.. 10M.. , as this will be an aggregated info.
6. Aggregating queries with joins are highly possible on any tables.

I know that the ecosystem of hadoop is big and can lots of combinations, so i would seek your help to guide me in this.

1. Hive can support part of the scenario like points 1,2 and 3.. but is it practical to use it this way (operational wise)
2. What else can be used to cover most of these scenarios? hbase, kudu.. a mix of other things?

Forgive me.. i am new to this

Answer (score 0):

You can try to leverage Apache Phoenix : http://phoenix.apache.org/
As the application is easy to install over HBase, allow tables definition and SQL grammar, also support views, also support secondary indexing.

Of course both joins and aggregation will come at a price. And still require a good model.